# Simple Question about Dirac Notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Hello I am doing introductory QM and I am getting myself hopefully confused with some Dirac notation. We have that
\begin{align*}
\langle x' | \psi \rangle &= \langle x' | \hat{I} |\psi \rangle \\
&= \int \langle x' | x \rangle \langle x|\psi\rangle dx \\
&=\int \delta(x'-x)\langle x | \psi \rangle dx \\
\end{align*}
then I am unsure on how to proceed to the next step. I simply want to obtain $\psi(x')$. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you want to obtain $\psi(x)$ rather than $\psi(x')$?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! Have fixed it,

Comment: Obtain $\psi(x)$ from what?   What's your starting point?  I guess I don't understand the question.  $\psi(x') = \left<x'\,|\,\psi\right>$, right?

Comment: So my main confusion is why that when we have any state $\psi$ that we may express it in terms of position as $\psi(x') = \langle x' | \psi \rangle$. Sorry, I should have worded it better.

Comment: see [Sifting Property](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SiftingProperty.html):$$f(x') = \int \delta (x' - x)f(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: So then $\langle x' | \psi \rangle = \langle x' | \hat{I} | \psi \rangle = \int  \langle x' | x \rangle \langle x | \psi \rangle dx = \int \delta(x'-x) \langle x | \psi \rangle dx$ and I just feel like I'm going in circles.

Comment: I think you're going in circles because you don't have a definition of what $\psi(x)$ is. $\psi(x)$ is, as the notation implies, a function of $x$. You find the value of the function by doing $\langle x|\psi\rangle$. So $\psi(x)=\langle x|\psi\rangle$. There is nothing to prove; this is just a definition. And without this definition, you'll never be able to "prove" the equality, because you won't even know what the object you're supposed to be proving things about is!

Comment: Another way to say this that you might like better: we want to represent $|\psi\rangle$ in the $|x\rangle$ basis. So $|\psi\rangle=\int \psi(x)|x\rangle dx$ for some coefficients we've named $\psi(x)$. From this definition of $\psi(x)$ you should be able to prove $\langle x|\psi\rangle=\psi(x)$. Again though, this includes a definition of $\psi(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, by definition, $\psi(x)=\langle x | \psi\rangle$. So you have

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\langle x'|\psi\rangle &=& \int\delta(x-x')\langle x | \psi\rangle dx\\
&=& \int \delta(x-x')\psi(x)dx\\
&=& \psi(x')\\
\end{array}
$$
where in the second step I used the definition of $\psi(x)$, and in the third I used the defining property of the delta function.

Of course, you could have gotten the result in step one just by using the definition of $\psi(x')$, without ever introducing the integral. But I'll assume you wanted to do it a hard way for some reason.

Comment: Ahh so then that means that $\langle x' | x'' \rangle = \int \delta(x-x') \delta (x-x'') dx = \delta (x'-x'')$. This makes a lot of sense, thankyou!

Comment: @Cococabana Right, it's all self-consistent. Although of course, that's not how you PROVE $\langle x'|x''\rangle=\delta(x'-x'')$; that's again just a definition. But performing those manipulations shows the definition is well-defined.